# Dynamically assign sm={} Attribute to Material Grid in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to assign dynamic value to the sm attribute of Material Grid. 
I am assigning it as

```js
  const headlines_grid_width = parseInt(props.headlines_grid_width)
```

and then in Grid

```
<Grid sm={{headlines_grid_width}} ...>
```

but it renders with the default value i.e. 12. 
On inspect  the class for that `<div>` comes as : 
`MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12`

```js
{
  other_headlines.map( headline => (
    <Grid item sm={{headlines_grid_width}} xs={12} key={headline._id} style={{borderRight:"0.1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220)",borderBottom:"0.1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220)",padding:"0.5%",paddingBottom:"0%"}}>

      <small style={{textDecoration:"none",fontWeight:"lighter"}}>
          <span style={{float:"left",textTransform:"capitalize",color:"red"}}>{headline.news_type}</span> 
          <span style={{float:"right"}}>{headline.date}</span> 
        </small>
      <h2 style={{paddingTop:"1%"}}>
        <Link href={`/article/${headline.heading}`}>
          <a>{headline.heading}</a>
        </Link>
      </h2>
      {/* <p>
        {headline.subheading}
      </p> */}
    </Grid>
  ))
}
```

Comment: You have an extra pair of curly braces around the value. When defining attributes in JSX, the curly braces indicate either a raw value or a variable value. Look at the `xs` and the `key` attributes for your Grid for respective examples. So, because `headlines_grid_width` is just an integer, your `sm` property should just be `sm={headlines_grid_width}`

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, thanks for the quick reply.